# Locking a table during mysql transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I am running several mysql queries with PHP to change values in several tables.

Basically something like this (simplified pseudocode)

```
$amount = (SELECT amount FROM wallet WHERE id = 1);
$amount = somelongcomplicatedtask($amount);
(UPDATE wallet SET amount = $amount WHERE id = 23);
```

There can be many scripts working with the mysql database (writing/reading) in parallel and I need to make sure the following is ensured:

- If one of the queries fails, all work done so far is reverted (I can use TRANSACTIONS for this)
- While I work with the two rows in the table wallet (1 and 23) they need to be locked, so any process (except the current one) wanting to read or write them has to wait. (Locking the whole table would be fine too, if it's not possible to lock only the rows)

The table uses InnoDB engine.

The problem is, that if I lock the table with `LOCK TABLES wallet WRITE` and then run `START TRANSACTION`, this will clear the lock. And if I first run `START TRANSACTION` and then I lock the table with `LOCK TABLES`, then the lock will COMMIT the started  transaction... those two things just turn each other off, yet I need both of them active at the same time.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL InnoDB storage engine already supports for row-level locking.
In this case, you have to take an exclusive lock on that particular row so other transaction will wait until and unless the first transaction releases his lock. More information : [InnoDB Locking Explained](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
longcomplicated...
UPDATE ...
COMMIT;
```

InnoDB's `FOR UPDATE` is important so that it locks the row until the `UPDATE` (actually until the `COMMIT`).

However, if the `BEGIN`...`COMMIT` takes "too long", you will encounter other problems.  The default timeout is 50 seconds, which is much too long for any civilized transactional setup.  If it is too long, then we need to discuss other locking techniques.

Do *not* use `LOCK TABLES`.